# Adding multiple assets to a resource with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm building a real-estate webapp, and every Ad should have an unlimited number of pictures (Asset).

In the Ad#new form I want to give the users the option to upload as many picture as they want.

I've created an Ad model which has_many Assets. An Asset is a model that holds a paperclip for a picture.

This is the code:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :picture
  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :large => "600x600", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

  belongs_to :ad
end


class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :contact_cell, :description, :price, :title, :user_id

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy
end
```

How should the form_for look like if I want to give the user the option to add unlimited # of photos before he/she submits the form?

Comment: You can get idea here http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with html5, you can easily do it by doing something like (the main important thing to notice, is that on html5 you can add the attribute multiple=true, that will create a multiple upload for you):

```
<%= simple_form_for(@ad, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :contact_cell %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :price %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= file_field_tag('ad_assets_picture', multiple: true, name: "ad[assets_attributes][][picture]") %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<%- end %>
```

otherwise you can just follow the nested form example, there is a [nice webcast about it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)